# Obtaining timing score of a implementation run with a PlanAhead TCL script

Tags: xilinx, vivado, planahead

In a PlanAhead TCL script, I need to know the timing score of a completed implementation run.

I have found an [old way to do this from 2012](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Implementation/Planahead-getting-time-score-with-tcl-scripts/m-p/255900#M5151). The solution is read directly the PAR report file.

In Vivado exist the *TNS* property that can be read directly with the *report_property* command. It exist a similar (and cleaner) way to obtain the timing score in PlanAhead?

Other options to obtain the timing score?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the only way to obtain the Timing Score is reading directly the PAR report.

Next the code posted by *Avrum* in [that old conversation at Xilinx forum](http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Implementation/Planahead-getting-time-score-with-tcl-scripts/m-p/255900#M5151)

```
set d [get_property DIRECTORY [get_runs impl_1]]
set f [glob $d/*routed.par]
set chan [open $f]
while {[gets $chan line] >= 0} {
  # puts $line
  if {[string match "Timing Score*" $line]} {set score [lindex $line 2] }
}
close $chan
puts "Timing Score is $score"
```

I have test it, and works fine.

Best regards